# Create ndarray from list with mismatched axis>0 size

Tags: python, numpy

I want to save a list of Numpy arrays to a file. The list is of the following shape:

```
my_list = [np.ones((2, 515, 3)), np.ones((2, 853, 3))]
```

However, when I try to save it using `np.savez`, the list tries to get converted into an Numpy array. Doing `np.array(my_list, dtype='object')` gives the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-6fcbd172df30> in <module>()
----> 1 np.array([np.ones((2, 515, 3)), np.ones((2, 853, 3))], dtype='object')

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,515,3) into shape (2)
```

However, if the `axis=0` dimension is mismatched instead of the `axis=1` dimension, such as `my_list = [np.ones((515, 3)), np.ones((853, 3))]`, I no longer get this error.

Why does the mistmatched axis dimension affect the ability to Numpy array from objects?

Although there are work-arounds possible to break up the array into a save-able format, I'm mostly interested about why the conversion failure is happening and how to get around it.

Comment: i think this my_list = [np.ones(2, 515, 3), np.ones(2, 853, 3)] will not work,have you seen the signature of ones? np.ones(shape,type,order)?

Comment: have you tried with this my_list=[np.ones((2,515,3)),np.ones((2,853,3))]
?

Comment: shape is the one that specify the axis,(2 is row(axis 0,515 is column(axis=1)

Comment: @Eliethesaiyan oops, I copied the wrong code. I fixed it now.

Comment: my_list has no fiunction to writing into files what you can do is np.savez("time",my_list[0],my_list[1]),.write them one by one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [77]: my_list = [np.ones((2, 515, 3)), np.ones((2, 853, 3))]
```

Save with the `*args` parameter, or with a `**kwargs` dictionary

```
In [78]: np.savez('test',*my_list)
In [79]: ll = np.load('test.npz')
In [80]: list(ll.keys())
Out[80]: ['arr_0', 'arr_1']
In [81]: ll['arr_0'].shape
Out[81]: (2, 515, 3)
In [82]: ll['arr_1'].shape
Out[82]: (2, 853, 3)
```

or with named keywarods/dictionary

```
In [85]: np.savez('test',x=my_list[0],y=my_list[1])
```

`np.savez('test', my_list)`, first turns `my_list` into an array - or tries to

```
In [83]: np.array(my_list)
...
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,515,3) into shape (2)
```

When trying to create an array from a list of arrays there are 3 possible outcomes: a higher dimensional array (if dimensions match), an object array (if dimensions don't match), or this error (if the dimensions sort-of match).

The object dtype case:

```
In [86]: arr=np.array([np.ones((515, 3)), np.ones((853, 3))])
In [87]: arr.shape
Out[87]: (2,)
In [88]: arr.dtype
Out[88]: dtype('O')
```

The surest way to create an object array is to preallocate it

```
In [90]: arr = np.zeros((2,), object)
In [91]: arr[...]=my_list
```

The shape of `arr` has to match the nesting of the sublists/arrays in `my_list`, otherwise you'll get broadcasting errors. `arr` can be reshaped after loading.

Comment: Is there a way I can force the object case? That's what I'm trying to do in my question, but I appear to be doing it wrong.

Comment: The surest way is to preallocate an object array of the correct size and dtype, and copy the list to it.